# How can I move content into tabs from elsewhere on the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

I'm looking to move some content on a page, into a set of tabs higher on the page via javascript or any other means. I can't edit WHERE on the page this code exists, but I can set Pre/Post HTML on the fields and thus give it a class or an ID to mess with.

[I built it out here to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/zp9cs6jw/)

If you don't want to go there, here's the code:

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #0090bf;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

````html
```
<!-- I can edit this section as needed. -->
<section class="panel panel-persondetails">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab1')">Tab Name 1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab2')">Tab Name 2</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab3')">Tab Name 3</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 3
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- The following is elsewhere on the page and I can't move it. I can add pre/post HTML which is how I'd wrap it in a div and give it an ID or class to hopefully use js to show it in the tabs above instead. -->
<div id="content-tab-1">I want this in tab1.</div>

<div id="content-tab-2">I want this in tab2.</div>

<div id="content-tab-3">I want this in tab3.</div>
````

Where are the JS experts locked in quarantine and itching for a problem to solve? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your JSFiddle and I think that I did the thing that you were asking. Initially, the content below the tabs is set to the contents of the element that said, "I want this in tab1". After that, the program simply gets the corresponding content each time you switch to a different tab. Here's the link to the JSFiddle:

[Tab Switching Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L0j5a6fp/2/)

```js
// START WITH THE CONTENT AS THE FIRST TAB ITEM
var contents = document.getElementById("content-tab1").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("tabcontent").innerHTML = contents;
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  // MAKE ALL OF THE TABS LOOK INACTIVE
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //CHANGE THE DISPLAY AND CSS PROPERTIES OF THE CLICKED TAB
  var contents = document.getElementById("content-" + tabName).innerHTML;
  console.log(contents);
  document.getElementById("tabcontent").innerHTML = contents;
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  
  console.log(evt.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #0090bf;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- I can edit this section as needed. -->
<section class="panel panel-persondetails">
  <div class="tab">
    <button id="tab1" class="tablinks active" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab1')">Tab Name 1</button>
    <button id="tab2" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab2')">Tab Name 2</button>
    <button id="tab3" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab3')">Tab Name 3</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
    <div id="tabcontent">
      replace me with stuff 1
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<br>

<!-- The following is elsewhere on the page and I can't move it. I can add pre/post HTML which is how I'd wrap it in a div and give it an ID or class to hopefully use js to show it in the tabs above instead. -->
<div id="content-tab1">I want this in tab1.</div>

<div id="content-tab2">I want this in tab2.</div>

<div id="content-tab3">I want this in tab3.</div>
```

Comment: This is very close... but I'm not wanting the content to still appear below the tabs after it's moved into the tabs. Any idea?

Comment: Actually if I make the content-tab1 ID set to display: none; that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Heads up that doing this (display:none) will result in duplicate data on the page.  That may not matter for you, but duplicate IDs cause unexpected behavior, and you'll also have double the memory usage.  I would suggest moving the element instead of copying it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
var newContent = $("#content-tab-1]").detach();
$("#tab1").find("div").first().html(newContent);
```

Obviously you'll have to put that wherever you need it, and expand for tabs 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

insertToTab(1);

console.log('tablinks ', tablinks);

for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].addEventListener('click', bindClick2(i))
}

function bindClick2(i) {
  return function() {
    insertToTab(i + 1);

    for (j = 0; j < tabcontent.length; j++) {
      tabcontent[j].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (j = 0; j < tablinks.length; j++) {
      tablinks[j].className = tablinks[j].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    var tabName = 'tab' + (+i + 1);
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    this.className += " active";
  }
}

function insertToTab(i) {
  var currContentTab = document.getElementById("content-tab-" + i);
  var currTabcontent = document.getElementById("tab" + i)

  currTabcontent.innerText = currContentTab.innerText;
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #0090bf;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel panel-persondetails">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active">Tab Name 1</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Tab Name 2</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Tab Name 3</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <div>
      replace me with stuff 3
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="content-tab-1">I want this in tab1.</div>
<div id="content-tab-2">I want this in tab2.</div>
<div id="content-tab-3">I want this in tab3.</div>
```